How can I replace direct references "@ file" on requirements file?
I want to run some Python scripts from this repository. The repository contains the instructions to run the scripts, including a requirements.txt file. However, the versions for some modules are not specified, but include direct references (to, as I understand, a local directory).
This is an extract of the listed modules:
addict==2.4.0
apex==0.1
appdirs==1.4.4
audioread==3.0.0
av==10.0.0
blessed==1.20.0
brotlipy==0.7.0
certifi @ file:///croot/certifi_1671487769961/work/certifi
cffi @ file:///croot/cffi_1670423208954/work
charset-normalizer @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/charset-normalizer_1630003229654/work
click==8.1.3

When I use pip to install the modules from the requirements file I get this error: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/croot/certifi_1671487769961/work/certifi'. As you note, certifi, cffi and charset-normalizer from the previous extract present the same sort of direct references instead of an explicit version.
This answer explains how to interpret direct references, when they are URLs, i.e. not as in the requirements file I want to work with.
I would like to know how to manually replace such references (if there is a way to do so) or what workaround exists for this issue. I am using pip on venv.

I'm not sure what kind of answer you are looking for. To manually replace them, use whatever text editor you like to change @ ... to whatever reference you can use to specify the location of the package. The problem with this file is that it implies the repository owner has some version of the packages with local changes that you can't get from anywhere public. It's not really "ready" for the public to use.

Just remove the @ file.... and let PIP get the most recent compatible version.
addict==2.4.0
apex==0.1
appdirs==1.4.4
audioread==3.0.0
av==10.0.0
blessed==1.20.0
brotlipy==0.7.0
certifi
cffi 
charset-normalizer 
click==8.1.3

